# reactjs - get a subset of an nested array objects

Tags: reactjs, arrayobject, nested-object, object-object-mapping

I have a variable like this, which I am passing as an input into the react app.

```
const options = [{"label": "Gryffindor", "value": "Gryffindor", "description": "Daring, strong nerve and chivalry.", "color": "#00ffa2"},
      {"label": "Slytherin", "value": "Slytherin", "description": "Cunning and ambitious. Possibly dark wizard.", "color": "#84d2ff"}]
```

From the above array i want to achieve the following output:

```
const TAG_COLORS:any = {
  Gryffindor: '#00ffa2',
  Slytherin: '#84d2ff',
}
```

can some one suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you are after:

edit. my bad misread the question.

```js
  const options = [{"label": "Gryffindor", "value": "Gryffindor", "description": "Daring, strong nerve and chivalry.", "color": "#00ffa2"}, {"label": "Slytherin", "value": "Slytherin", "description": "Cunning and ambitious. Possibly dark wizard.", "color": "#84d2ff"}];
 
var TAG_COLOURS = {};
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  TAG_COLOURS[options[i].label] = options[i].color;
}

console.log(TAG_COLOURS);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day. This works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the map function to create a JavaScript object and then use the JavaScript object method on it.

This is how you may go about it:

```js
var options = [
{
 "label":
     "Gryffindor", "value": "Gryffindor", "description": "Daring, strong nerve and chivalry.", "color": "#00ffa2"}, 
{
 "label": 
     "Slytherin", "value": "Slytherin", "description": "Cunning and ambitious. Possibly dark wizard.", "color": "#84d2ff"}
]


options.map((data)=>{console.log(Object.values(data))})
```

Hope this answers your question